# What is the minimum number of rounds that A must take in order to meet B at the starting point? The speed of A and B are $4$ m/s and $12$ m/s resp.

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

What is the minimum number of rounds that A must take in order to meet B at the starting point? The speed of A and B are $4$ m/s and $12$ m/s respectively

Answer is 1 but according to me answer must be $3$ since,
multiples of 4 are= 4,8,12,16..
multiples of 12 are= 12,24....

A moving with the speed of 4 m/s will take 3 rounds and B moving with the speed of 12m/s will take 1 round and then they will meet. Because lowest common multiple is 12.

Answer (score 0):

The discrepancy between your answer and the book's answer is that you are counting the number of rounds made by person $A$, but the book is counting the number made by person $B$. You are both correct.

The only problem is a communication error. In my opinion, this is a bad question because "the number of rounds" is a vague phrase that does not specify whose rounds it is counting.

Comment: U reversed A and B

Comment: He is counting B and book is asking about A’s